# How to avoid "unnecessary" indentation in long class definitions?

Tags: python

In both Perl and C++ 
one has an option to write class method definitions by defining the
method outside the class and thereby avoiding en extra level of
indentation.

Of course those language are
free form (in contrast to Python) so you do not strictly need to add indentation for each
nesting level, but one usually does so for readability.

For example, in C++ the following class definition (approach #1):

```
class X {
    void x_method(int a, int b) {
        // implementation details follows here.. Note: extra indentation
    }
};
```

can also be written with the method definition outside the class (approach #2):

```
class X { 
    void x_method(int a, int b);
};
void X::x_method(int a, int b) {
    // implementation details follows here
}
```

In Perl, you could write the first version as:

```
package X {
    sub x_method {
        my ($a, $b) = @_;
        # implementation details follows here
    }
}
```

and you can avoid the extra indentation for the method definition by using this style:

```
package X; 
sub x_method {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    # implementation details follows here
}
package Y; # marks the start of another class
# ...
```

In these
examples I used a small class definition that extends less than the
amount of lines that can be viewed on a computer screen (let's say
less than 50 lines). For such definitions, approach 1 with the method
inside the class is fine. However, once the class definition becomes
hundreds of lines, I would prefer approach #2 by defining the class
methods outside the class.

However, I cannot find this approach in Python. How can I do appraoch
 #2 in Python?

It seems to me
that you only have approach #1 in Python:

```
class X:
    def x_method(a, b):
         //implementation details follows here
```

I would like to have something similar to this (approach #2):

```
class X:  
def x_method(a, b):
    # implementation details..

class Y:  # marks the start of another class
# ...
```

When the number of methods (and lines) in a class definition
 increases, I think appraoch #1 becomes more and more verbose.
Then, the only purpose I can see that the extra space (indentation) has, is
to indicate that a method belongs to a given class X. 
And that information (that a method belongs to a given class), does not
need to expand and propagate over more and more lines as class
definition grows. It is quite sufficient to contain that information to a
 single line as in Perl (using the package statement), or to a single prefix word as
 in C++ using the namespace resulution prefix operator on the method
 name in the first line of its definition.

I am not so familiar with Python, and coming from these other lanuages
it feels like I am suffocating in redundant space (using approach #1)
for large class definitions, and it distracts me from my programming
tasks. What am I missing here?

Extra indentation also forces you to break more lines to keep within
the recommended 80 characters per line limit.

Comment: Indentation is mandatory in Python, you can't get away from that. However, I only imagine this would be an issue if you code is becoming deeply nested, in which case you could probably refactor it to reduce the nesting

Comment: I have never seen someting which would do similar in python...

Comment: Avoiding indentation is not really the reason C++ allows you to implement methods outside of the class body – keeping headers and implementations apart is, which goes back to the C workflow of compiling every source-file separately and letting dependencies only see the header files. — Seriously, that one level of indentation shouldn't matter, else it's an indication that you're doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: you could indent on 2 spaces rather than 4. not PEP8, and dense, but less hacky than subverting class structures.  indents only have to be consistent within theor block scope anyway.  Still, running out of indent space may be a code smell showing the desirability of refactoring long methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have approach #1 in python because in addition to classes there may be top level function definitions so python will not be able to find out if `global_function` in the example below is really global or belongs to class `X`:

```
class X:  
def x_method(a, b):
# implementation details..

def global_function(x):
# implementation

class Y:  # marks the start of another class
# ...
```

There's however one way to decrease indentation like this (but it pollutes global namespace with functions that belong to the class):

```
def x_method(self, b):
#implementation

class X:
    x_method = x_method
```

Answer (score 3):

As @RomanKonoval has hinted at, methods are just values in python, you you can monkey patch them on as you would any other value:

```
def _some_method():
    pass

class Foo:
    some_method = _some_method
```

**But, Python is not C++ or Perl. You probably don't want to do this!**

You should look to follow [PEP8 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It almost certainly would discourage this pattern. If indenting your code 4 spaces more makes the lines too long (PEP8 says you should wrap at 79 columns) then you are probably trying to do much (on each line and perhaps within that method). You should strive for small, composable functions where each line is succinct and obvious. You can use line continuations where appropriate where lines must overflow. For example:

```
some_method(that, takes, a_long_list, of_parameters,
            that_overflows, onto_the, next_line)
```

Beyond style, there are some practical reasons not to do this. For one, if you make use of python's optional typing, I'm fairly certain mypy won't understand that `some_method` is an instance method on `Foo` (you might see similar issues with other static analysis tools like flake8). Now I'm not saying that you should avoid something just because the tooling doesn't understand it. But, I that code would be initially confusing to me and I suspect others looking at it might get initially tripped up.

**edit:** Another point I just thought of: (again along the lines of `Python != C++ or Perl`) Python as a language made the design decision that meaningful whitespace leads to better code. And indeed, well written Python scripts read like English and are organized into easily digestible paragraph-like phrases. If you circumvent this just to avoid one level of indentation, you are making your code harder to read for most python programmers.

Comment: PEP8 doesn't have 16/9 screens :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre PEP8 wants you to be able to vsplit a few files and a shell on your 16:9 screen ;)

Comment: It also makes your code more code review friendly in github and other similar tools which respect PEP8 more than 16:9 monitors.

Comment: the github argument is solid. fortunately most of the code I write isn't open source :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre even (or _especially_) on a big screen, long lines are hard to read. Bad idea to fill that hspace just because you have it! That said, I find 79 a bit overzealous, IMO it should be allowed to use up to 96 if there's no convenient earlier breakpoint.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yeah. POB,. I'm using about 110 chars. After what I just want to CTRL+A/Delete the whole thing.

Comment: I used to hate the 79 columns rule (in fact, I would disable that rule in all my projects), but I've come to appreciate it. I recently have been finding that with optional typing the type signatures cause lines (especially method signatures) to overflow. This requires wrapping, which sometimes is a little ugly, but I've found it's also encouraged me to make good refactorings of type names (say replacing `Tuple[int, int]` with `Point`).